# ICMP sent to wrong interface

Tags: windows-10, routing

I have set up the below network at home.
From the Tower PC I can ping the Laptop on 192.168.2.1. But the from the Laptop I cannot. Both computers run Windows 10.

[image]

WireShark shows that the ICMP request frame goes to the TP Link (on the Wi-Fi interface) instead of the Switch (on the eth interface).

```
Frame 10: 74 bytes on wire (592 bits), 74 bytes captured (592 bits) on interface 1
Ethernet II, Src: AskeyCom_fa:a3:86 (e0:ca:94:fa:a3:86), Dst: Tp-LinkT_22:d3:82 (30:b5:c2:22:d3:82)
    Destination: Tp-LinkT_22:d3:82 (30:b5:c2:22:d3:82)
    Source: AskeyCom_fa:a3:86 (e0:ca:94:fa:a3:86)
    Type: IPv4 (0x0800)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 192.168.0.108, Dst: 192.186.2.153
Internet Control Message Protocol
```

I'm sure this is due to bad routing. And the ping from the Tower PC to the Laptop probably only works because the reply is done by default to the same interface where the request came from.

Here is how I tried to set it up. These are the Laptop interfaces configurations:

```
Ethernet adapter Ethernet
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Qualcomm Atheros AR8161/8165 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet Controller (NDIS 6.20)
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-26-6C-17-74-09
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.2.1(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Qualcomm Atheros AR9485WB-EG Wireless Network Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : E0-CA-94-FA-A3-86
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.108(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : 01 October 2017 21:26:37
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : 03 October 2017 01:26:30
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

And this is the default routing table:

```
IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.0.1    192.168.0.108      4
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
      192.168.0.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.0.108    258
    192.168.0.108  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.0.108    258
    192.168.0.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.0.108    258
      192.168.2.0    255.255.255.0         On-link       192.168.2.1    257
      192.168.2.1  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.2.1    257
    192.168.2.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.2.1    257
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link       192.168.2.1    257
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.0.108    258
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.2.1    257
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.0.108    258
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

I would expect this rule to do the trick but it doesn't:

```
      192.168.2.0    255.255.255.0         On-link       192.168.2.1    257
```

I also tried to change the metric of the rule to 2, 6 and 400 but it didn't work either. Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are barking up the wrong tree because of a typo when you issued the `ping` command.

> Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 192.168.0.108, Dst: 192.186.2.153
>                                                                                               ^^^

Notice the **186** instead of 168. That's why it followed the default route and chose the source IP address assigned to that interface.

Comment: Do I feel utterly stupid right now or do I just feel utterly stupid right now? :-/ Anyway, just proof that reuse in the command line can be tricky... :-)

Comment: I make this mistake so often that whoever owns 192.186.1.0/24 probably thinks I'm trying to hack his machines.